# How to reuse variables in java with selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have 4 test scripts for my application. In every scripts, I am using data driven framework to test with multiple values. So each time in each script, I initialize the necessary variables which are almost common in all scripts. Is there any possible to way reuse these variables or constants in java or selenium??

**below is my code**

```
static String excel,sheet;

    @BeforeClass
        public void start(){
            driver.findElement(By.id(""));
        }

        @DataProvider
        public static Object[][] chartDetails() throws IOException{
            excel = Init.readConfig("xls");
            sheet = Init.readConfig("sheetName");
            data = ReadData.getData(excel, sheet);
            return data;    
        }

    @Test(dataProvider="chartDetails")
    public static void generateCharts(String standName,String termName) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("script goes here"));
       Assert.assertEquals("actual","expected");
    }
```

In above code, the declaration part will be common in all modules. so i want to reuse the same variables.

Comment: @SajanChandran added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are these test scripts implemented as Java classes? If so, there are two common ways to do this.

Create a superclass that each of the 4 tests scripts inherit from which defines the shared variables and shared logic to populate them.

```
public BaseTest {
    protected sharedVariable1;
    protected sharedVariable2;
    protected sharedVariable3;

    @Before
    public void sharedInit() {
        sharedVariable1 = //..
        sharedVariable2 = //..
        sharedVariable3 = //..
    }
}

public Test1 extends BaseTest {
    @Before
    public void specificInit() {
    }
}
```

Or, create a separate class which only holds the shared variables and shared logic and use this class in each of the 4 test scripts.

```
public Shared {
    private sharedVariable1;
    private sharedVariable2;
    private sharedVariable3;

    public Shared() {
        sharedVariable1 = //..
        sharedVariable2 = //..
        sharedVariable3 = //..
    }
}

public Test1 {
    private Shared shared;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        shared = new Shared();
    }
}
```

Comment: @sh0ruguru nice answer..I think 2nd choice will be better. I also think the 2nd solution before posting question.

Comment: @sh0ruguru wat about the first one?? could n't understand lil bit

Comment: JUnit will execute any `@Before` methods in base classes. Sticking a `@Before` method in a superclass is a good way to make that method run in all base classes. Also, JUnit guarantees to run `@Before` methods in base classes first, so the shared initialization will be done before the specific initialization.

Comment: @sh0rugur thanks a lot...so creating baseclass and initialising all common variables in that class will be a good solution